# Excel File Upload And Download in Opencart 1.5+

Tags: php, excel, file-upload, opencart, shopping-cart

I want to upload product-lists which is a excel file with .xls and .xlsx file extension.I search Google and stack overflow and added all the below contents:
Allowed File Extensions:

```
txt
png
jpe
jpeg
jpg
gif
bmp
ico
tiff
tif
svg
svgz
zip
rar
msi
cab
mp3
qt
mov
pdf
psd
ai
eps
ps
doc
rtf
xls
ppt
odt
ods
xlsx
xltx
potx
ppsx
pptx
sldx
docx
dotx
xlam
xlsb
```

and

```
Allowed File Mime Types:
text/plain
image/png
image/jpeg
image/jpeg
image/jpeg
image/gif
image/bmp
image/vnd.microsoft.icon
image/tiff
image/tiff
image/svg+xml
image/svg+xml
application/zip
application/x-rar-compressed
application/x-msdownload
application/vnd.ms-cab-compressed
audio/mpeg
video/quicktime
video/quicktime
application/pdf
image/vnd.adobe.photoshop
application/postscript
application/postscript
application/postscript
application/msword
application/rtf
application/vnd.ms-excel
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text
application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.template
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.template
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slideshow
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.slide
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.template
application/vnd.ms-excel.addin.macroEnabled.12
application/vnd.ms-excel.sheet.binary.macroEnabled.12
```

But still not able to upload excel file using the server explorer.It showing warning : incorrect file type !

I just want to upload excel files from admin panel and show a link on the website homepage in a widget so my visitor could easily download it with a single click.

I am using Opencart Version 1.5.5.1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just copied and pasted ur code.
In mine works perfectly

Comment: could you able to upload excel file through website ?And let me know if it was browse-able and select-able through server explorer window under upload button.Could you send me the demo link where i could see it.Thank you.